# Recreating views across SQL Servers using powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, sql-server-2012

I am trying to use Powershell to read the definition of a view and a stored procedure from a SQL Server. Grab the definition as a create possibly and execute this in a new server on a database with the same name.

Any ideas to help me get started on this? I am new to Powershell.

Comment: So is the ending result you want is to just write a powershell script that will execute a Sproc?

Comment: Ultimately yes.  But it has to grab the sproc/view Def from a source.  I am envisioning a way to grab the text from a Create view statement and execute it in the new server.

Comment: Is the Sproc in a SQL 2005 or 2008 server?

Comment: It is actually in SQL server 2012

Comment: But on the new server for creating view you must have all the reference tables

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started. I am not sure what all you will have to do, but this will run a stored procedure in PowerShell.

I used the article below for this information. 
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3683181/Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell-and-SQL-Server-2005-SMO-150-Part-II.htm

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=HOME\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Integrated Security=True"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "sp_helpdb"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close()
$DataSet.Tables[0]
```

You could possibly do something more like this, I am not sure if you are using PowerShell Community Extensions or not, but here you go (only for 2008 and up):

1.) Add the plug-ins

```
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100

Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100
```

2.)Use Invoke-SQLcmd

```
$query = "EXEC nameofsproc"
$db = "nameofdatabase"
$instance = "(local)"
$user = 'sa'

invoke-sqlcmd -query $query -database $db -serverinstance $instance -Variable
```

Below is a website that describes creating a View in Powershell in detail:

http://bi-bigdata.com/2013/03/10/powershell-tutorial-for-creating-view/

Comment: This could just be my lack of Powershell experience but how is this reading from the source? I see it uses exec to execute the defenition on the new server, but at what point do I read the original?

Comment: I guess I am not exactly sure what you mean by reading from the source. The code above is allowing you to execute a pre-made Sproc and the website shows you how to create a view in PowerShell.

Comment: Oh ok I think I see now.  Sorry about that.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that for a creating views you already have all the reference tables in the new server

```
Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking

$serverName = 'your_source_InstanceName'
$dbname = 'your_source_DbName'
$destServerName = 'your_destination_InstanceName'
$destdbname = 'your_destination_DbName'

$destSrv = New-object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server" $destServerName
$destDb = $destSrv.Databases[$destdbname]

$srv = New-object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server" $serverName
$db = $srv.Databases[$dbname]

$scr = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter"
$scr.Server = $srv
$options = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.ScriptingOptions"
$options.AllowSystemObjects = $false
$options.SchemaQualify = $true
$options.ClusteredIndexes = $true
$options.Default = $true
$options.DriAll = $true
$options.Indexes = $true
$options.NonClusteredIndexes = $true

#Set options for SMO.Scripter
$scr.Options = $options

#StoredProcedures
$StoredProcedures = $db.StoredProcedures | where {$_.IsSystemObject -eq $false}
Foreach ($StoredProcedure in $StoredProcedures)
{
    if ($StoredProcedures -ne $null)    
    { 
     Try{
     $destDb.ExecuteWithResults($scr.Script($StoredProcedure))     
     }
     Catch{        
     $err = $Error[0].Exception
     Write-host "Error caught: "  $err.Message; 
     While ($err.InnerException){
     $err = $err.InnerException;
     Write-Host "Inner exception:" $err.InnerException.Message;
     };      
     return;
     }
    }
}

#Views
$views = $db.Views | Where {$_.IsSystemObject -eq $false}
Foreach ($view in $views)
{
    if ($views -ne $null)
    { 
     Try{
     $destDb.ExecuteWithResults($scr.Script($View))     
     }
     Catch{        
     $err = $Error[0].Exception
     Write-host "Error caught: "  $err.Message; 
     While ($err.InnerException){
     $err = $err.InnerException;
     Write-Host "Inner exception:" $err.InnerException.Message;
     };      
     return;
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alex,  Yes I will have all of the dependent tables in the destination server. I am going to give this a try I think it should work, looks like it is exactly what I am looking for.   i will let you know how it works out. Thanks!